# Testing angular component's controller with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

This is my component:

```
const comp = {
    controller: 'gridDetailsNavigationCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/shared/grid/navigation/gridDetailsNavigation.html',
    bindToController: true,
    bindings: {
        viewData: '<',
        listState: '@',
        detailsState: '@',
        pagingData: '=',
        backSpinnerId: '@',
        stateParams: '<'
    }

};
```

This is part of the component's controller:

```
class GridDetailsNavigation {
    constructor($rootScope, $scope, $state, tipaltiConsts) {
        this._$state = $state;
        this._$scope = $scope;
        this._$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this._consts = tipaltiConsts;
    }

    $onInit() {
        ....
    }
    $onDestroy() {
        ...
    }
    goToNext() {
        ....
    }
    goToPrev() {
       ....
    }            
  }
```

I'm trying to test the component and its controller. I'm able to create a component and even get its controller scope:

```
 const component = compile(angular.element(template))(scope);
 scope.$digest();
 component.$onInit();
 // get controller in two different ways.
 const $ctrl = component.scope().$ctrl;
 const $ctrl2 = component.controller('gridDetailsNavigationCtrl');
```

My problem is that the $ctrl returns only scope properties and public methods e.g goToNext and goToPrev are not defined, and $ctrl2 is undefined.

I know I can use $componentController but I want the component itself and from it to get the controller. What am I doing wrong here? Why are methods unreachable? why is the second controller undefined?

Thanks